# Reset tf2 settings to default and update them in steam cloud

Tags: team-fortress-2, steam-cloud

Yeah so a long long time ago I used Chris's High FPS config to get better framerates on a crap laptop, but ever since, every new computer I've had has broken sprays.

Ideally I want to keep most my settings but also take the defaults on things I care less about. Which means I might have to do some manual diffing.

- How can I get TF2's default settings back? (and What should I backup first?)
- How can I diff the default settings with my own (I use Ubuntu/linux, so *where* are all the settings hidden, places windows hides settings would too be helpful).
- And how can I make steam cloud reflect the settings I decide on?

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for the 'nuclear' option - i.e. wanting to *completely* reset TF2, here's what I found works in order to reset TF2 to defaults:

> **Caution:** This will remove **everything** not tied to your Steam account, including Mods, HUDs, Configs/Scripts, as well as Graphics/Sound and Advanced settings.
>
> It will **not** reset your achievements or playtime stats.

#### 1. Temporarily disable TF2's Steam Cloud Sync

Right Click on TF2 -> Properties -> Updates -> Uncheck 'Enable Steam Cloud synchronisation':

[image: TF2 Properties window]

#### 2. Remove the "cfg" folder

Located at `<Install Location>\Steam\steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\`

#### 3. Remove anything in the "custom" folder

Don't remove the whole folder, just anything inside it

#### 4. Put "-autoconfig" in TF2's launch options

Right Click on TF2 -> Properties -> General -> Set Launch Options

[image: Launch Options]

#### 5. Start TF2

At this point everything will reset to default. You can now quit the game, reenable Steam Cloud & remove the '-autoconfig' launch option.

Comment: Why is it necessary to temporarily disable cloud sync?

Comment: @ReedDunkle your configs and settings are saved to the Steam cloud, I believe it's because if they aren't present on startup (say, from a fresh install) it will auto-download them from the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get TF2's default settings back? (and What should I backup
>   first?)

Right click the Game in the Library menu, click Properties, click on Local Files, and select Verify Integrity of Game Cache.

[image]

If you have modifications to the game what Verifying the Integrity will do is check your version with the official version on the server, and download the official settings if something does differ.

---

> How can I diff the default settings with my own (I use Ubuntu/linux,
>   so where are all the settings hidden, places windows hides settings
>   would too be helpful).

You can also backup game files. If you have custom content in TF2, whether it be a different hitsound, model replacements, custom configs, these will ultimately all be located in this path folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\custom
```

Navigate there, copy everything into a folder like I do, so that if you do verify the game integrity and settings get wiped you can place those mods back into the custom folder right away.

[image]

---

> And how can I make steam cloud reflect the settings I decide on?

Unfortunately I'm not too sure how Steam Backups work with custom content.